# Azure default subscription not found

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been trying to create a powershell script to create an Azuer firewall rule on the fly.

The code I'm using is:

```
$servername = "xxx" 
$username = "xx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = "xxx" 
$subscription = "Pay-As-You-Go" 
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 
$password -AsPlainText -Force $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secpasswd) 

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -SubscriptionName $subscription

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription -Default

$ipAddress = (Invoke-WebRequest 'http://myexternalip.com/raw').Content -replace "`n"

New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $servername -RuleName 'Test' -StartIpAddress $ipAddress -EndIpAddress $ipAddress
```

I also get the following errors:

Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Pay-As-You-Go doesn't exist.

and

New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default 
subscription.

I'm also tried changing the Login-AzureRmAccount to Add-AzureAccount but it didn't make any difference. The user I created is an owner of the SQL server.

Is there anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing AzureRM and Azure modes...  You need to make sure the subscription you want is accessible from that mode.  If you login with Login-AzureRMAccount or Add-AzureRMAccount - use Get-AzureRMSubscription to see what you have access to.

If you login with Add-AzureAccount, use Get-AzureSubscription...

Check that and see what you find.

Comment: Ah right. I've now added the line:Get-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription | Set-AzureRmContext which I found on Google but the New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule still throws an error complaining about the default subscription.Is there a RM equivalent?

Comment: Found it: New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule. Only issue was it now needs the resource group name but that was easy to extract. Many thanks